# Linq: How to find rows searching in two columns with the same criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

In my controller, I've this action method called "*SearchForContact*," which takes 2 strings parameters *firstName* and *LastName*. There are 3 situations:

- If both parameters are null, the view is redisplayed with an error message, prompting the user to enter at least one of the 2 parameters
- if both parameters are not null, I can retrieve contacts and display the result on the view
- **Unfortunately**, when either of the parameters is null, I get nothing. I suspect that I did not write correctly my ***Linq Statements***.

here's the statement that process the search:

```
var contacts = contactRepository.SearchForContacts(firstName, lastName).ToList();
```

Here are my helper methods located in my repository class (ContactRepository.cs) located in the models folder.

```
public IQueryable<Contact> SearchForContacts(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (firstName == null)
            return OneCriteria(lastName);
        if (nom == null)
            return OneCriteria(firstName);
        else
            return TwoCriteria(firstName, lastName);

    }
    private IQueryable<Contact> OneCriteria(string criteria)
    {
        var contacts = from contact in db.Contacts
                       where ((contact. firstName == criteria) ||
                              (contact. lastName == criteria))
                       orderby contact. firstName
                       select contact;
        return contacts;
    }
    private IQueryable<Contact> TwoCriteria(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var contacts = from contact in db.Contacts
                       where ((contact. firstName == firstName) &&
                             (contact. lastName == lastName))
                       orderby contact. firstName
                       select contact;
        return contacts;
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Should you not change

```
if (nom == null)
```

to

```
if (lastName== null)
```

Seems to work fine when i tested it.

Comment: I've corrected the mistake, but it still not working when I use one criteria

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if ((firstName == null) && (lastName != null)  )
        return OneCriteria(lastName);
```

if ((firstName != null) && (lastName == null)  )
            return OneCriteria(firstName);

else
            return TwoCriteria(firstName, lastName);

hope this helps.

Comment: Ali62,

I tried what you said, it didn't work. However, while following the flow of the execution. Instead of null, I rather saw "" -- Empty string. I then replaced null by Empty string and it worked. I wonder what happened.

Comment: glad to here you find your answer yourself .
may behind the scene somewhere is process .NET converts string nulls to Empty string you mentioned I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:
if(firstName == null && lastname == null)
{do your error}

else
{

var contacts = from contact in db.Contacts select contact;

if(firstName != null) contacts = from FN in contacts where (FN.firstName == firstName) select FN;

if(lastName != null) contacts = from LN in contacts where (FN.lastName == lastName) select LN;

}